# Dagger retrofit cannot be provided

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit2, dagger-2

Admiteddly,Dagger is tough and I am trying to inject Retrofit. I injected Context And SharedPreferences and it works fine.But Retrofit broke it all.
It recognizes the DaggerRetrofitComponent class but doesnt find DaggerAppComponent.

Retrofit Module:

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    @Provides
    HttpLoggingInterceptor getHttpLoggingInterceptor(){
        return new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

    }
    @Provides
    OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor){
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
    }
    @Provides
    GsonConverterFactory getGsonConverterFactory(){
        return GsonConverterFactory.create();
    }
    @Provides
    Retrofit getRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory, OkHttpClient client){
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
                .client(client).build();
    }
}
```

Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static AppComponent appComponent;
    public static AppComponent getAppComponent(){
        return appComponent;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent=buildComponent();

    }


    protected AppComponent buildComponent(){
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }

        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().sharedPreferenceModule(new SharedPreferenceModule()).contextModule(new ContextModule(this)).build();


    }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ContextModule.class, SharedPreferenceModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

RetrofitComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RetrofitModule.class})
public interface RetrofitComponent {
    void injectRetrofit(Activity activity);
//
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    Context context;
    @Inject
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DaggerRetrofitComponent.builder().retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule()).build().injectRetrofit(this);
        MyApplication.getAppComponent().inject(this);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this class:

```
//@Singleton
//@Component(modules = {RetrofitModule.class})
//public interface RetrofitComponent {
//    void injectRetrofit(Activity activity);
//
//}
```

and modify `AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ContextModule.class, SharedPreferenceModule.class, RetrofitModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

Comment: This works but how do I separate application and activity level dependencies

Comment: Retrofit is not an Activity level dependency, it's marked with `@Singleton`.

Comment: Yes I get that . But could you give an example on activity level dependencies (Not retrofit necessarily).

Comment: @Bissisingh your presenter for your activity is an example of an activity scoped dependency.

Comment: @mt0s But do i inject the presenter for example, other than the fact that i can dump everything in application level which doesnt seem good.

Answer (score 0):

Dagger 2 does not allow to inject dependencies from multiple components. You should consider using subcomponents.

https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html

UPD: I would suggest you to create subcomponent derieved from your AppComponent, for instance NetComponent. And then provide getNetComponent.inject() in your activity. Since NetComponent would be derieved from AppComponent it will provide all dependencies from appComponent you need

Its a bit more complex, but its a right way to do it, also you should learn about Dagger Scopes.

OR

The fast way just put your networking dependencies into AppComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to make Retrofit a component (a module from your app component should be enough), then you should use last Dagger version to handle automatic injection for your controller views (activities and fragments)

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication>
{
    override fun inject(application: MyApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder
    {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: MyApplication): Builder

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

__

```
@Module(includes = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,ActivityBuilderModule::class, NetworkModule::class])
abstract class ApplicationModule
{
    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindApplication(application: MyApplication): Application

    @Module
    companion object
    {
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @ApplicationContext
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideApplicationContext(application: MyApplication): Context = application
    }
}
```

__

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule
{
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity

    //others activities there
}

@Module
object NetworkModule
{
    // For simplicity just retrofit provider, but all others network resources should be here of course

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideRetrofit(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory,
                        nullOrEmptyConverterFactory: Converter.Factory,
                        @ApplicationContext okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
                        gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
            .addConverterFactory(nullOrEmptyConverterFactory)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
}
```

__

```
class MyApplication : DaggerApplication()
{
    private val applicationInjector = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
        .application(this)
        .build()

    public override fun applicationInjector() = applicationInjector
}
```

__

Then from your activities/fragments make them inherit from DaggerActivity or DaggerFragment and you should be able to do your inject out of the box

You may have a look to my template project https://github.com/SamYStudiO/beaver it'll may help.

ps : Sorry it's all kotlin but should be easily convert to java

Comment: Kotlin isnt  an issue but i havent studied most of those annotations  like JVMstatic yet.

Comment: What is ActivityBuilderModule?

Comment: I added it (it's useful to create activities subcomponents from app component), check my github link at bottom if you miss something everything come from it

Comment: @JvmStatic is just an annotation to tell java it's a static method since kotlin as no static keyword

Comment: MainActivityModule? I cant seem to find it on the github repo

Comment: Here it is : https://github.com/SamYStudiO/beaver/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/net/samystudio/beaver/ui/main/MainActivityModule.kt, if you have specific dependencies with your MainActivity that where to put them.

Comment: Annotations arent allowed before companion object in Application Module. I replaced companion object with a static block though.

Comment: Indded to convert to java, for each companion block you should remove them, remove @JvmStatic and make the method static

Comment: Sorry,too complicated for me to understand as a beginner who just learned about Modules and Provides